# replaceState() and pushState(): What is global browser history?

Tags: javascript

> history.replaceState() operates exactly like history.pushState()
>   except that replaceState() modifies the current history entry instead
>   of creating a new one. Note that this doesn't prevent the creation of
>   a new entry in the global browser history.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Can anyone explain what is global browser history? how is it different from the normal browser history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means `history.replaceState()` could add an entry in your browser history (`Ctrl+H` on most browsers), though it won't add an entry to current history (i.e. browser back button behaviour)

Comment: let's say `url1 -> url2 --> (url2-replaced) -> url3` then if i press back button from url3 it lands me to url2 not url2-replaced. Am i Correct!?

Comment: It lands you on `url2-replaced`. If you back once more, you land on `url1`